# Outer Join with Sub-query (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, subquery, outer-join

I need an outer join to a table that is limited by a sub-query. However, Oracle is returning

```
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a sub-query
```

I then tried pushing the outer join inside another sub-query but as the original sub-query depends on a field from the main table it is being joined to, this fails with

```
ORA-00904: "DTL"."TRANS_DATETIME": invalid identifier
```

Can anyone suggest how this join can be resolved?

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM header  hdr
JOIN detail  dtl
    ON hdr.trans_number = ptd.trans_number
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  product_code
                   ,cost_price
            FROM prodcost pr
            WHERE pr.last_amend_date = (SELECT MAX(pc.last_amend_date)
                                        FROM   prodcost pc
                                        WHERE  pc.product_code = pr.product_code
                                            AND pc.last_amend_date <= trunc(dtl.trans_datetime))) p
    ON ptd.product_code = p.product_code
```

**Explanation**
I have `header` and `detail` tables that join on transaction number (this is actually irrelevant to the issue and can be considered a single table). I then need to left join the `prodcost` table on `product_code`. However, I have to restrict this based on the most recent `last_amend_date` prior to `trans_datetime`

So the `detail` table is a record of transactions with product IDs (`product_code`) and a transaction date (`trans_datetime`). The `prodcost` table has a record of the product costs with product IDs (`product_code`) and an effective date (`last_amend_date`). So a single product can have multiple costs depending on when the transaction took place. To identify the correct cost, I need to link on `product_code` and the most recent `last_amend_date` prior to `trans_datetime`.

I am aware I could split this into two queries and `UNION` them to provide the complete result set. However, I'd rather avoid that if at all possible. Any other suggestions on how to resolve would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `ptd` referring to?

Comment: If you could share some sample data and your expected output, it would be easier to understand the requirement.

Comment: The reason for that error is quite clear: `dtl.trans_datetime` is not a column on table detail. A typo perhaps?

Comment: @wvdz actually, I suspect the issue is that the dtl.trans_datetime column is referenced too far down in the subquery - in Oracle, references are scoped to one level down.

Comment: Yes, the issue in the query above is that `dtl.trans_datetime` is referenced from two levels down, which Oracle does not support. However, if it is moved up a level, then I have the issue with ` a column may not be outer-joined to a sub-query`

Comment: Some additional explanation added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of examples that ought to help you achieve what you're after (I made up my own tables/data since you declined to provide sample data, but the principle remains the same and you should be able to apply it to your own queries):

**Example 1 (using left join and an analytic function):**

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, to_date('02/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, to_date('03/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'c' val from dual union all
            select 4 id, to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'd' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, 100 val, to_date('01/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 1 id, 120 val, to_date('12/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 1 id, 130 val, to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 2 id, 200 val, to_date('01/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 3 id, 300 val, to_date('04/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 3 id, 330 val, to_date('06/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual)
-- end of mimicking two tables, t1 and t2, containing data. See SQL below:
select id,
       t1_dt,
       t1_val,
       t2_val
from   (select t1.id,
               t1.dt t1_dt,
               t1.val t1_val,
               t2.val t2_val,
               t2.dt t2_dt,
               row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t2.dt desc) rn
        from   t1
               left outer join (select id,
                                       val,
                                       dt
                                from   t2) t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t2.dt <= t1.dt))
where  rn = 1;

        ID T1_DT      T1_VAL     T2_VAL
---------- ---------- ------ ----------
         1 01/01/2016 a             120
         2 02/03/2016 b             200
         3 03/02/2016 c                
         4 04/01/2016 d
```

**Example 2 (using a scalar subquery):**

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, to_date('02/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, to_date('03/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'c' val from dual union all
            select 4 id, to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'd' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, 100 val, to_date('01/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 1 id, 120 val, to_date('12/12/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 1 id, 130 val, to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 2 id, 200 val, to_date('01/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 3 id, 300 val, to_date('04/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
            select 3 id, 330 val, to_date('06/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual)
-- end of mimicking two tables, t1 and t2, containing data. See SQL below:
select id,
       dt t1_dt,
       val t1_val,
       (select max(val) keep (dense_rank first order by t2.dt desc) max_val
        from   t2
        where  t1.id = t2.id
        and    t2.dt <= t1.dt) t2_val
from   t1;

        ID T1_DT      T1_VAL     T2_VAL
---------- ---------- ------ ----------
         1 01/01/2016 a             120
         2 02/03/2016 b             200
         3 03/02/2016 c                
         4 04/01/2016 d
```

N.B. I'm assuming that t1.id is unique.